# CSS: Fluid box resizing while keeping aspect-ratio (with padding-top)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize an image placeholder (hereafter referred to as box) of which I know the aspect ratio (x:y is 1:0.6). So far I was able to get most of it to work (I solved it with the padding-top relative to the width trick). The only problem is, that the container seems to ignore both max-width and max-height and thus becomes larger than the box insides. Is there a way to limit the size of the padding-top relatively to either max-width or max-height? Or how can I stop it from growing too much vertically?

This is what I've tried so far:

HTML

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%:
}

.container {
    background-color: #aaa;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding-top: 60%;
    height: 0;
    max-height: 420px;
}

.box {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 420px;
}
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pg92gc7o/2/

Comment: have you considered using viewport relative units like `vw/vh`?

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a simplified example. The actual container and box are nested in other elements.

Comment: It's not ignoring the max-height, its that the height is set to 0 and the padding-top is set to 60% of the body the "height" of the container is just the padding

Comment: Yes, thanks. But the 60% should be referring to the container's width, shouldn't it? So if the width itself can never be more than 700px, then the padding should never be more than 60% of that.